# Reading /dev/input/js0 from Java

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to read `/dev/input/js0` from Java but I keep getting

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

My code is

```
import java.io.*;

final class Test {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/dev/input/js0");
                    System.out.println(in.read());
            } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

My end goal is to be able to read input from my controller but I can't even seem to read one byte. What am I doing wrong? My user does have read and write access to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the `FileInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: What did you do once you had this information? I can't seem to figure out the byte structure.

Comment: @MatthewSegreti the structure is listed here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/joystick-api.txt what I recommend is doing `DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/dev/input/js0")));` and then using the `DataInputStream` to read data since you can easily read into int, short, and byte data types.